# how to save my name,score and levels played in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In a game with 5 levels, how to save a name, highest score, levels(which currently he is).

Answer (score 4):

Probably using `NSUserDefaults` is the easiest way to go.  Me and my team came up with a nice class that encapsulates the use of this class for you...

http://getsetgames.com/2009/10/07/saving-and-loading-user-data-and-preferences/

Comment: thanks  a lot. If i Restart again without quitting i have the saved score but i didnt get my saved value when i reopen and compile.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your situation.  When you say you restart without quitting what do you mean exactly?  Do you mean restart without quitting from the simulator, running on the device, etc.?

I could see saved data not being preserved on a re-compile/re-deploy to the simulator/device as it may be a new binary and therefore considered to be a new program.  Not sure and just a guess at this point.